# controller and link functions in directive do not have same scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with my **angular.js directive**.

It should be a kind of autocomplete, in directive's **controller** property I'm loading an array of values and inside **link** function compiling template to show the results.

But when I update `scope` inside **link** it doesn't reflect on controller and template, please take look at the example here - http://plnkr.co/edit/Lz3QGwklghPo3as2QTqU

Should I `apply` scope changes or smth similar?

Comment: why you are manually compiling the template ??

Comment: because inside compile it's the same behavior..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems

- Attach click event to document instead of body
- Use $apply() inside bind

Below code will resolve your problem

```
$document.bind('click', function (e) {
                    scope.results = [];
                    scope.$apply();
                });
```

Comment: +1 thanks a lot, it resolves this issue, is it always necessary to ``$apply`` when using angular's compiler?

Comment: You need to use $apply() when you are working outside angular context ,bind function belongs to Jqlite (or Jquery if jquery is included on page) so this function does not belong to angular so you have to use $apply().

Answer (score 1):

I update your `$body.bind('click',...)` method to

```
$body.bind('change', function (e) {
    scope.results = [];
});
```

and it seemed to work (I mean that after 0.5 sec I typed a letter, the list of name is re-displayed).